# Why does $f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c \ge 0\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ imply $f$ has at most one real distinct root and discriminant $D \le 0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Why does $f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c \ge 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ imply $f$ has at most one real distinct root and discriminant $D \le 0$?

I've been wondering why the following result is true. Intuitively it seems to be true if you consider the graph of a polynomium of degree 2 that doesn't intersect the $x$-axis twice. However this is by no means rigorous and I think the answer should be simple, since the text is introductory.

Comment: $f$ is quadratic, it *cannot* have just one real root. Complex roots *must* come in pairs. Are you sure this isn't supposed to be a cubic.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Take $a=1$, $b=c=0$.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann oh he is talking about repeated roots. Technically it still is 2 roots, $0$ and $0$.

Comment: I mean different roots. I know $f$ must have 2 roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen is my answer satisfactory?

Comment: $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a\left[\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{D}{4a^2}\right]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ had two distinct roots, these would be simple roots, hence at each of these the function changes sign. As the function is nowhere negative, this is impossible.

Comment: I really like this justification. You mean we can write $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$ and because $a \neq b$ it must change sign twice.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yes but not $a$ and $b$ you fool ;)

Comment: I mean $a,b \in\mathbb R$ not the coefficients (my fault).

Answer (score 1):

The roots are $$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{D}}{2a}$$

If $D\lt0$, and assuming that the coefficients are real, the roots must be complex clearly, in which case we have $0$ real roots.

If $D=0$, $$x=-\frac{b}{2a}$$ is the only solution obviously.

The above is assuming $a\ne 0$, if it is equal to $0$, then $x=\frac{-c}{b}$ trivially.

Comment: How do you use the fact that $f(x) \ge 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen in assuming that $a\gt0$

Comment: The proof works otherwise as well. If $f\le 0\forall x\in \Bbb R$ the proof is still correct. Actually that statement in the question is unnecesary. $D\le0$ implies either $f\ge0$ or $f\le0$ by the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thank you. You should write $a > 0$ in your answer and write why this must be true for $f(x)\ge 0$:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let's assume a is positive, otherwise we take -a

$$f(x) = a[(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}+\frac{c}{a}]$$

$$f(x) = a[(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a}](*)$$

I just tried to force a square, do you see how it is equal to the initial f?

Now this quantity has a minimum for $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ and as we know f is positive, therefore the quantity on the right in the main equation (*) is necessarily positive. It's $-\Delta >0$ the discriminant that is defined like $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$. The discriminant is negative.

Note that $f(x) = 0$ on $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ if and only if the discriminant is zero. That is what we call a double root.

EDIT : By the way, a **has** to be positive if the function stays positive. If you take the limit in $+\infty$ it behaves the same way as $ax^2$ so the positivity implies $a>0$